# Convert Keycode to char in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, keycode

When a key is pressed in my custom View, OnKeyPress is called:

```
public DrawView(Context context, IAttributeSet attributeSet) : base(context, attributeSet)
{
        KeyPress += OnKeyPress;
}

private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        Keycode code = e.KeyCode;
        // How to convert to char?
}
```

How do i convert the Keycode to a char? For instance:

```
"Space" -> " "
"Enter" -> "\n"
"A"     -> "A"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
public override bool OnKeyUp (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    char keyPressed = (char) e.GetUnicodeChar();
    Log.Debug (string.Format ("On KeyUp is:{0}", keyPressed));
    return base.OnKeyUp (keyCode, e);
}
```

Comment: Your code is not completely valid because the KeyPress event takes a KeyEventArgs as a paramter. Not KeyEvent.

Comment: @SteffanPallesen :  I just made a sample to share idea. Well I'm not pretty good sure about the codes. But the logic is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Vaikesh's answer, this is the solution:

```
private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char c = Convert.ToChar(e.UnicodeChar);
}
```